# is it possible to assign variable inside Array[' add variable here '] in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

Is it possible to assign a variable inside the array[' $addhere ']? I assigned a value in a variable and I want to put it in []

this is the variable

```
@php
    $order_id=$orderItem->id;
@endphp
```

And I want to put it here,

```
{{$partialDeliveries[$order_id]->stock_in_qty}}
```

error response

[image]

Table in blade

```
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none" id="orders"  >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="">Product Code</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($order->orderItems as $orderItem)
                    @php
                        $order_id=$orderItem->id;
                    @endphp
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $orderItem->product_code }} {{$order_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $orderItem->product_name }} {{$partialDeliveries[$order_id]->stock_in_qty}}</td>
                        {{-- <td> {{$orderItem->quantity}}</td> --}}
                        <td><input type="number" name="stock_in_qty[]" id="stock_in_qty_{{$orderItem->id}}" class="form-control stock_in_qty" min="1" value="{{$orderItem->quantity}}" data-max="{{$orderItem->quantity}}" onkeyup="check(this);"/></td>
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                            var $orderItem_id = {{$orderItem->id}};
                            $('#stock_in_qty_'+$orderItem_id).on('mouseup keyup', function () {
                                $(this).val(Math.min({{$orderItem->quantity}}, Math.max(1, $(this).val())));
                            });
                        </script>
                        <td> {{ Form::date('delivery_date[]',today(), ['class' => 'form-control date', 'style' => 'width:200px;','required']) }}</td>
                        <td>{!! Form::text('delivery_note[]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                        @if ($errors->has('delivery_note'))<span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('delivery_note') }}</strong></span>@endif
                        </td>          
                    </tr>
                    {!! Form::hidden('product_id[]', $orderItem->product_id) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('stock_in_qty[]', $orderItem->quantity) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('order_id[]', $order->id) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('order_item_id[]', $orderItem->id ) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('company_id[]', $order->company->id) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('stock_out_qty[]',null) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('transfer_to[]', null) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('user_id[]',auth()->user()->id ) !!}
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried it, and got an error? Because it seems as it should work, you can use a dynamic variable as the array index for sure.

Comment: Hi @nakov I just update my question.

Comment: Is $partialDeliveries a collection?

Comment: The error means that you don't have item on the 17th index. So it cannot retrieve it. When you build the collection make sure you use the same ids.

Comment: ahh wait i think what I need to put inside it is the number of loop. [0], [1], [2] since I have 3 itmes in the loop it works. yeah I think thats what I need to put.

Comment: It works now, {{$partialDeliveries[$key]->stock_in_qty}} thanks guys for the responses!!